# How to use GPU and CPU in tensorflow (keras)?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, memory, neural-network, tf.keras

I am running a rather memory-intense (estimated to be around 6GB) GAN model with tf.keras which my GPU doesn't seem to be able to handle (predicting fails, reports only nans). Is there a way to support my 4GB GPU memory with system memory? Or a way to share the computational effort between GPU and CPU?

### My specs:

- OS: Windows 10 64
- GPU: Geforce GTX 960 (4GB)
- CPU: Intel Xeon-E3 1231 v3 (4 cores)
- Python GUI: Spyder 5
- Python: 3.8.5 / 3.8.10 in a conda environment with only the tensorflow and chess module installed
- Tensorflow: 2.5
- CUDA: 11.2.2
- cudnn: 8.1.1

For more information see my very detailed version of this question I asked a couple of days ago (no responses, hence this one): [TF model doesn't predict anymore after switching to GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794264/tf-model-doesnt-predict-anymore-after-switching-to-gpu)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

In tensor flow to train a model with a `gpu` is the same with any operating system when using python `keras`.When you train the model you wrap your training function in a `with` statement specifying the `gpu number` as a argument for the `tf.device method`

**Here is a template of the code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/device:GPU:<The gpu number>'):
    history = model.fit(<your traning info>)
```

Otherwise if you lack the resources such as RAM CPU GPU then try to use [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com)  a free environment to program tensor flow with access to many GPUS's CPU's and RAM for free

Comment: Thanks for the input, TERMINATOR. Since I didn't have any issues activating my GPU, I'm glad you added the reference to Google Colab. That indeed might be the way forward for me.

Comment: Can I please ask for a link to the papper you read on his for personal use

Comment: I am using code that's originally from the pix2pix project (see https://github.com/phillipi/pix2pix). Victor S has made this model usable in a chess environment here: https://towardsdatascience.com/magnusgan-using-gans-to-play-like-chess-masters-9dded439bc56?gi=f00faa8a2105

Comment: I found something you might be interested in here https://towardsdatascience.com/facemask-detection-using-tensorflow-and-opencv-824b69cad837